# SwipeCellKit: Why removing an item from list, doesn't update the UITableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I remove an item from list with SwipeTableViewCell, the tableview doesn't get updated.
The swiping works, I can also tap on the delete button behind the cell, but once tapped on it, it only hides the delete button but tableview is not updated.
This is how my code look like:

```swift
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return carList.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_id", for: indexPath) as! CarCell

        (cell as SwipeTableViewCell).delegate = self
        
        let car = carList[indexPath.row]
        cell.configure(with: car)

        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {
        
        guard orientation == .right else { return nil }
        
        let deleteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, indexPath in
            
            self.carList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        }
        deleteAction.hidesWhenSelected = true

        return [deleteAction]
    }
```

It works when I call reloadData of the tableview, but it's not the correct way I guess. The following snippet of code works:

```swift
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {
        
        guard orientation == .right else { return nil }
        
        let deleteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, indexPath in
            
            self.carList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            
            self.tableView.reloadData() // <-- this works! But without animation
        }
        deleteAction.hidesWhenSelected = true

        return [deleteAction]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the code to update the view but instead of reloading the entire table view just *delete* the row

```
let deleteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, indexPath in
        
    self.carList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
}
```

Comment: I thought SwipeCellKit has a method to auto trigger the tableview to update data. In the source code on [SwipeCellKit](https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit/blob/develop/Example/MailExample/MailTableViewController.swift) from line 141, there's no `self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)`, but it does the same behaviour. How is that possible?

Comment: I don't know `SwipeCellKit` but as you wrote it worked with `reloadData` I wrote my answer. I cannot even see the benefit of  `SwipeCellKit`.

Comment: SwipeCellKit adds swipe feature on existing customised UITableViewCell. Once customised, you can't use the default swipe functionality anymore, hence SwipeCellKit.